# JMeter TestLogicalAction START_NEXT_ITERATION_OF_CURRENT_LOOP - what it means?

Tags: jmeter

https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.TestLogicalAction.html

The docs does not say what is result of START_NEXT_ITERATION_OF_CURRENT_LOOP and I could not find out via web search.
What's the difference from START_NEXT_ITERATION_OF_THREAD?

To give other angle to the question, for `test action sampler` `go to next iteration` is applicable to `current thread` only, not to all threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `START_NEXT_ITERATION_OF_THREAD` == `Start Next Thread Loop` - applies to [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) iterations
- `START_NEXT_ITERATION_OF_CURRENT_LOOP` == `Go to next iteration of Current Loop` - can be applied to nested [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller), doesn't trigger next Thread Group iteration

---

Given you use `Test Action` my expectation is that you're sitting on one of the previous JMeter versions as this sampler has been renamed to `Flow Control Action` in [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5).

[According to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading on the version you will find at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page on next available opportunity.

Comment: Thanx. I'm actually trying to upgrade from ver2. I found in docs `setRestartNextLoop` is deprecated, whereas in ver 5 it simply does not work as I've found out. The upgrade issue (slow load of old script) maybe deserves separate question.